# Three JS texture is not showing up

Tags: three.js, textures

I am trying to apply a texture to my 3D model with Three JS.
I tried a lot of ways from the Three JS Examples but for any reasons nothing is working.

Here is how I apply the texture to my model:

```
    //LOADING TEXTURE

    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    var diffuse = textureLoader.load( "models/Carbon.png" );
    diffuse.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    diffuse.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    diffuse.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    diffuse.repeat.x = 1;
    diffuse.repeat.y = 1;

    var normalMap = textureLoader.load( "models/Carbon_Normal.png" );
    normalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    normalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;


    var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        roughness: 0.5,
        clearcoat: 1.0,
        clearcoatRoughness: 0.1,
        map: diffuse,
        normalMap: normalMap
    });

// LOADING MODEL

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load("models/stairs.gltf", function(gltf){
        model = gltf.scene

        model.traverse((newModel) => {
            if (newModel.isMesh){
                newModel.material = material;
                newModel.castShadow = true;
                newModel.receiveShadow = true;
            }
        });

        scene.add(model);
    });
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a texture for a `glTF` model, you have to set `Texture.flipY` to `false` to satisfy the uv convention of `glTF`.

```
diffuse.flipY = false;
normalMap.flipY = false;
```

Besides, you always have to ensure that your model has texture coordinates. You can do this by checking if the geometries of your meshes have an `uv` attribute. If this attribute is missing, I suggest you generate texture coordinates in a DCC tool like Blender.

`three.js R112`

Comment: Ah nice! The texture coordinates where missing. Thank you :-) !

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.